# how to reset a field to '1' in a table after it reaches 999 in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `table_1` with two columns: `NUMBER_FIELD_1` and `FIELD_2`.

I have the below query:

```
SELECT FIELD_2 AS FIELD_2,
max(NUMBER_FIELD_1) AS NUMBER     
FROM TABLE_1
group by FIELD_2
```

How to alter the above query to check if max of `NUMBER_FIELD_1` reaches `999` and if it does then reset it to `1`.

Comment: [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)

Comment: Do you want to alter the results of the query or the contents of the table?

Comment: I need to alter the above query to check if the maximum of number_field_1 value is 999 in the table, if yes then the number_field_1 value in the table  should reset to 1.

Comment: Makes little sense to me.  So if the max is 1001 then nothing is changed?

Comment: Hi paparazzi im incrementing number_field_1in the table_1 using some other code. So now i want to check with my above sql query whether number_field_1 value is 999 and if yes then reset the field to 1.

Comment: Do you just want it in your resultset, or update the table?

Comment: I just want in resultset

Answer (score 0):

I usually use modular calculations for this.  i.e. the remainder when divided by a number.

check out this, to see if it gives you an idea of how to achieve.

```
SELECT 998 % 1000, 999 % 1000, 1000 % 1000, 1001 % 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's solution looks like the sensible solution. Here is another option though, maybe this is more intuitive:

```
SELECT  T.NUMBER_FIELD_1
,       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY grp.frmID ORDER BY T.NUMBER_FIELD_1) RN
,       T.FIELD_2
FROM    TABLE_1 T
INNER JOIN (
                VALUES(1, 999)
                ,     (1000, 1999)
                ,     (2000, 2999)
            ) grp(frmID, toID)
        ON  T.NUMBER_FIELD_1 >= grp.frmID
        AND T.NUMBER_FIELD_1 <= grp.toID
```